# How to trigger a Jenkins job as a release, from another job

Tags: build, jenkins

I have several release builds on my jenkins, with parameters such as version, username, etc. If I build them from "Release" button, all of them work. However, if I try to trigger one from another, then the triggered job is run as if I pressed "build now", rather than use "release" variation, with parameters. This isn't what I would like, but I don't know how to "release" one job, and have it trigger release of another, with the same parameters.

I am sorry if I am not clear, I am very clueless about jenkins so far, but this needs to be done and I need help.

Comment: Hi! Do you have an answer for your question? The answer that you have chosen doesn't really provide any information

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trigger "perform maven release" of a jenkins job from another job](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39605276/trigger-perform-maven-release-of-a-jenkins-job-from-another-job)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You need the [Parameterized Trigger plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) for Jenkins; if you don't have this plugin already and don't have administrative access to Jenkins, you'll need to get an admin to help you.

Comment: I do have it, but whenever I asked for the job to be triggered, from the first one, I get the same type of build that I would if I pressed "build now", and not "release". The prerelease scripts don't get run as a result.

Comment: Sounds like you're not passing the correct parameters to the downstream build.  Can you post a screen shot of the "trigger parameterized build" build step ?

Comment: I am having the same question, but what are the "correct parameters"? I tried to use the parameters that the second release job requires, but it is still run as normal build, not as a release build. What is the magic to trigger a release build in the second job from the first job?

Comment: Can @OksanaK or gareth_bowles answer what the parameters should be to trigger a build as a release? This answer is not useful for others trying to solve the same issue