# Trigger "perform maven release" of a jenkins job from another job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Looking for ways to trigger a "perform maven" release job from another jenkins job. It can be a rest api (or) a plugin that can do it. I saw posts about "trigger paramterized" plugin which can do this, but I cant see a way to do it . So I need real examples on how to try it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This [task](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-29519) has been open in Jenkin's Jira since July 2015 with no movement yet.

Since this is the case, I suggest using an **HTTP POST** to accomplish this task.  To do this, you will need to do the following:

1. Install the [HTTP Request Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTTP+Request+Plugin)
2. Create an httpUser (or use an existing one) with the appropriate [Matrix Permissions](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Matrix-based+security) and then grab its API Token **Jenkins** -> **People** -> **httpUser** -> **Configure** -> **API Token** -> **Show API Token...**[image: Show API Token...]
3. **Jenkins** -> **Manage Jenkins** -> **Configure System** -> **HTTP Request** -> **Basic/Digest Authentication** -> **Add** -> create a Global HTTP Authentication Key with the information from ***step 2***
   [image: Global HTTP Authentication Key]
4. Create a "parent" job that will trigger other Jenkins job(s) via the [M2-Release-Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/M2+Release+Plugin) and configure it as follows:
5. **This build is parameterized**

   - releaseVersion (Text Parameter)
   - developmentVersion (Text Parameter)
   - (add other parameters as required, look in the [doSubmit method](https://github.com/jenkinsci/m2release-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jvnet/hudson/plugins/m2release/M2ReleaseAction.java) for details)
6. **Build** -> **Add build step** -> **HTTP Request**

   - **URL** (should have this format) = http://**JenkinsServerName**/job/**JenkinsJobName**/m2release/submit
   - **HTTP mode** = POST
   - **Advanced...**
   - **Authorization** -> **Authenticate** = select the Authenticate option created in ***step 3***
   - **Headers** -> **Custom headers** -> **Add**
   - **Header** = Content-type
   - **Value** = application/x-www-form-urlencoded
   - **Body** -> **Pass build params to URL?** = Yes
   - **Request body** = (your parameters from step 5 and a json parameter object with any additional parameters required)
   - **Response body in console?** = Yes
     [image: HTTP Request]

These are the steps I followed to have one Jenkins job trigger an m2release on another job in my environment.  Hopefully this helps others and should I lose my notes or memory, I can refer to this post as well.

Comment: wow! thank you so much for the detailed explanation. I wish I can give you more than 1 point for this answer..

Comment: Great thing. Also there is an option to pass custom parameter in the job that does release via json query parameter `json={"parameter": {"name":"CUSTOM_PARAM_1", "value":"CUSTOM_PARAM_1_VALUE"}}`